# Node num_detectors + 1 in detector_error_model_to_pymatching_graph

Tags: stim

I understand that the node num_detectors is the boundary node, but what's the use of node num_detectors + 1? The code is from the [honeycomb boundary paper](https://github.com/Strilanc/honeycomb-boundaries/blob/main/src/hcb/tools/analysis/decoding.py#L282). What are spandrels?

```
# Add spandrels to the graph to ensure pymatching will accept it.
# - Make sure there's only one connected component.
# - Make sure no detector nodes are skipped.
# - Make sure no observable nodes are skipped.
g.add_node(num_detectors + 1)
    for k in range(num_detectors + 1):
        g.add_edge(k, num_detectors + 1, weight=9999999999)
    g.add_edge(num_detectors, num_detectors + 1, weight=9999999999, qubit_id=list(range(num_observables)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are spandrels?

A "spandrel" is an unintended byproduct of achieving some other goal. See the wikipedia article on [spandrel (biology)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spandrel_(biology)). In the specific case of this code, the extra nodes are spandrels because they're not really wanted (they're not really relevant to the problem) but are instead a byproducts of trying to explain the decoding problem to pymatching v0.7.

The code you're referencing has very much been obsoleted in newer versions of pymatching. Nowadays pymatching understands stim objects, so you'd use [`pymatching.Matching.from_stim_circuit`](https://pymatching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pymatching.matching.Matching.from_stim_circuit) or [`pymatching.Matching.from_detector_error_model`](https://pymatching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pymatching.matching.Matching.from_detector_error_model) instead of artisanal python code.